# How to get info between 2 regexes in the order of appearance in a text?

Tags: java, regex

How can I get the info between < > and between " " ?

I tried linking the regexes with |, but it doesn't find anything.

```
String processed="";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|<(.*?)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    processed += matcher.group(1);
    processed += " ";
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are not finding the content in angular brackets is, you're not really printing it. You're assuming that `matcher.group(1)` will give you the group that is matched, either between `<>` or `""`, but it's not like that. Groups are numbered based on the parenthesis. Try printing `group 1` and `group 2` on each iteration, and you'll get to know what is happening.

After figuring out the issue, you just have to remove those capturing groups, and make them non-capturing one, and use `group(0)` instead, and it'll work:

```
String processed="";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(?:[^\"]*)\"|<(?:.*?)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    processed += matcher.group(0);
    processed += " ";
}
```